# Stop code behind from executing based on condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an ASP button that executes some JavaScript "Generate()" and then the code behind "Button2_Click".

`<asp:Button OnClientClick="Generate();" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="New Baseline >>>" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Style="float: right;"/>`

If "count" is greater than 0, I want to prevent the code behind from executing

```
function Generate() {
  var count = 0
  var ids = jQuery("#<%= JQGrid1.ClientID %>").jqGrid('getDataIDs');

  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var rowId = ids[i];
    var rowData = jQuery("#<%= JQGrid1.ClientID %>").jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);

    //alert(rowData.Action);

    if (rowData.Action == null || rowData.Action == "") {
      count += 1
    }
  }

  if (count > 0) {
    alert('You must complete all of the Actions fields first!');
    return false;
  } else {
    //All Action fields complete, continue to code behind...
  }
};
```

I have tried return false, but that does not stop the code behind.

Comment: What do you mean by "Stop code behind from executing"? You reference a function called "Button2_Click" but haven't included that code in the question.

Comment: If the JavaScript variable "count" is greater than 0, I don't want the code behind (Button2_Click) to execute. If the variable is 0 then I do want the Button2_Click function to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the generate value to the Button.

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="return Generate()"

<script>
    var test = 2;

    function Generate() {
        if (test === 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know why this has been marked down, its the correct solution to my reported problem! Thanks VDWWD

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in `OnClientClick="Generate();" OnClick="Button2_Click"`.

You're assigning two inline click events here, so they'll both trigger independently.

You have to handle the `Button2_Click` function from inside `Generate`.

One way you might do this is to call `Button2_Click` in the else condition:

```
  if (count > 0) {
    alert('You must complete all of the Actions fields first!');
    return false;
  } else {
    //All Action fields complete, continue to code behind...
    Button2_Click();
  }
```

Comment: `Button2_Click` is an aspnet server side method. Not a javascript one...